# How to Package Angular Project with SpringBoot application

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot Maven Project named Test inside my eclipse Workspace.

After that I create (with ng, following the Angular tour of heroes) an Angular client inside another folder on my system. Now if I launch with command line:

```
ng serve --open
```

inside my angular project folder and if I start my springboot server application I can run API GEt and others..

Temporarily I have manually added the content of dist folder obtained by the command

```
ng build
```

inside the *src/main/resources/static* folder that I have manually created in my SpringBoot project.

When I run by spring-boot:run and go to localhost:4200 it says *connection refused, check your proxy or firewall*

The goal would be package front end and back end to a single war runnable under tomcat.

Can you help me?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the copying process by configuring the Angular CLI to take build directly in the src/main/resources/static folder.
If you are using **Angular 6 or above**, you can change build output path in the **angular.json** file-

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace-schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular.io-example": {
      "root": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "MODIFIED DIST PATH",
            ...
```

The modified dist path will be a relative path to your static folder.

If you are using **Angular 5** or below, you can do the same in the **.angular-cli.json** file-

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "angular5-sample"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "MODIFIED DIST PATH",
      ...
```

Example- If your angular source code is in the src/main/webapp folder, then the modified dist path in the outputPath or outDir properties will be- '../resources/static/dist'.

This will create the dist folder directly in the src/main/resources/static folder. To tell SpringBoot that the index.html file is inside the src/main/resources/static/dist folder, you should update the static locations by adding the classpath of the dist folder in the **application.properties** file.

If you set the outputPath/outDir as '../resources/static' in the above example, then the build files will directly be generated in the src/main/resources/static folder. However, the Angular build process will delete the entire static folder and create a new static folder with the new build files each time you take an Angular build. You will lose any other files present in the static folder. So it is better to have a separate dist folder inside the static folder.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I find out a rough solution, but for now it's enough:

Create (everywere) an Angular Project by:

```
ng new angular-client
```

Build and deploy it by:

```
ng build --prod
```

put the content of dist file inside src/main/resources/static

```
maven clean install

spring-boot:run
```

An it works.
Clearly the copying procedure should be automated maybe by maven

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example directory layout for your project:

```
src
├── main
│   ├── java
│   │   └── com
│   │       └── domain
│   │           └── project
│   │               ├── Run.java
│   ├── resources
│   │   ├── banner.txt
│   └── webapp
│       ├── WEB-INF
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── app
│       │   ├── app.module.js
│       │   ├── app.utils.js
```

Instead of putting the Angular files inside `src/main/resources/static`, try creating a new web folder at `src/main/webapp` and inside it create a new `app` folder to store all the Angular code. This is also the default layout for web project in Maven.

In your `pom.xml` you can add this plugin:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp/</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Also in your `@SpringBootApplication` class `Run.java` add this snippet so that all 404 requests are routed back to `index.html` so that they are handled by Angular:

```
@Bean
public ErrorPageRegistrar errorPageRegistrar() {
    return (ErrorPageRegistry epr) -> {
        epr.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/index.html"));
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try this solution as soon as possible. Usually I doesn't put the Angular code inside eclipse because it generate errors.. Anyway I will try.

Comment: I don't understand if you mean to put all code inside my app folder or the dist content. Because if I put all the code, as expect, I have a lot of error inside node_modules folder. And then this way I will have 2 index.html, an index.html under webapp and another one under app (angular one)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below maven plugin dependencies to pack your app.
The project directory structure should look like something like this.

[image]

```
    <build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <warSourceIncludes>WEB-INF/**,resources/public/build/**</warSourceIncludes>
            <packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/**,resources/public/build/**</packagingIncludes>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
         <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.6</version>
         <configuration>
            <!-- optional: where to download node from. Defaults to https://nodejs.org/dist/ -->
            <nodeDownloadRoot>http://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
            <!-- optional: where to download npm from. Defaults to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/ -->
            <npmDownloadRoot>http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/</npmDownloadRoot>
            <workingDirectory>src/main/webapp/resources/public</workingDirectory>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>install node and npm</id>
               <phase>process-classes</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <!-- See https://nodejs.org/en/download/ for latest node and npm (lts) versions -->
                  <nodeVersion>v8.9.4</nodeVersion>
                  <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
               <id>npm config</id>
               <phase>process-classes</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>npm</goal>
               </goals>
               <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
               <configuration>
                  <arguments>config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/</arguments>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
               <id>npm install</id>
               <phase>process-classes</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>npm</goal>
               </goals>
               <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
               <configuration>
                  <arguments>install</arguments>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
               <id>npm run build</id>
               <phase>process-classes</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>npm</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <workingDirectory>src/main/webapp/resources/public</workingDirectory>
                  <arguments>run build</arguments>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

By executing `mvn clean install` your app will be packed and can be executed with java & Angular components.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you set `target/classes/static` as your angular build output dir into angular.json?

Answer (score 0):

Put your `dist` content after angular build into Spring Boot Java project under `src/main/resources/public` and then launch your Spring Boot app.

Answer (score 0):

Update spring boot application.properties with static resources property
spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/dist/app-ui

More details can be found here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.web.resources.static-locations